# React Native : What is the best practice to use global variables throughout your whole application?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on my first React project and I would like to use some kind of global variables but I'm having some trouble with understanding the flow and scope of variables in React.

After the user logs in I'm saving the username in the AsyncStorage, so it will be remembered, the next time he/she uses the app.

```
const loginUser = (username, password) => {

    // ... imaginary login fuctionality ...
    this.saveUserName(username);

}

saveUserName  = async (username) => {

    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("username",username);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }

};
```

After the authentication succeeds and the username gets stored, i use react-navigation to navigate to the HomeScreen.

```
saveUserName  = async (username) => {

    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("username",username);
        this.navigation.navigate("Home")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }

};
```

So I arrive on my Homescreen where I would like to show a welcome message containing the username.

```
return (

    <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
        <Text style={style.welcome}>Welcome [username should come here]</Text>
    </View>
)
```

Since the username will remain unchanged throughout the whole application, I would like to place it in some sort of 'global' variable, so I can be retrieved throughout the whole application. I tried retrieving it from the AsyncStorage again on the `homescreen` but because it's asynchronous, the page is already rendered.

Since i'm using react-navigation, i can retrieve the name from the AsyncStorage and pass it in the navigation function :

```
 let username = await AsyncStorage.getItem("username");

    this.props.navigation.navigate("Login", {
        username: username,
    });
```

This works, but it feels like a bad practice to manually pass this variable to every page where I want to show the username. Since the username doesn't change, I guess it would be overkill to retrieve it multiple times from the AsyncStorage?

Is there a way to retrieve all the values from AsyncStorage just once, and then store them in some kind of global variable, so that they can be used throughout the whole application?

I've read some articles stating that I can pass these variables to the state of my app, but I seem to understand that the variables only would be passed from parent to child? I made the Homescreen with a functional component which I understand is stateless, so I guess this isn't an option?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After the user logs in I'm saving the username in the AsyncStorage, so it will be remembered, the next time he/she uses the app.

This is out of the context of the question, but you need to save a token in async storage with which you can fetch the user object, and not store a username in async storage. If you don't have a token next time, then you cannot assume that the saved username is valid and the user is logged in. It's a massive security issue.

> Since the username will remain unchanged throughout the whole application

This is not true since user can log out, making the username invalid, and login with a different username.

> This works, but it feels like a bad practice to manually pass this variable to every page where I want to show the username. Since the username doesn't change

The username does change, which makes passing it in params worse since the passed username will become outdated if it did change in future. Regardless, data such as user data doesn't belong in params: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#what-should-be-in-params

> Is there a way to retrieve all the values from AsyncStorage just once, and then store them in some kind of global variable, so that they can be used throughout the whole application?

You need to store them in state after retrieving from async storage. Since you want to use this state in whole application, it's a matter of [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the root component.

Assuming you have a function component, you can store the state using React's `useState` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

To be able to use this state in all child components, you can expose the state using React context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

```js
function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState({ checking: true });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user_token').then(
      (value) => setToken({ checking: false, value }),
      (error) => setToken({ error })
    );
  }, []);

  if (token.checking) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }

  return (
    <UserTokenContext.Provider value={token.value}>
      {/* rest of app code */}
    </UserTokenContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

You may also want use a global state management library such as Redux or Mobx State Tree if you need to store more than just a token.

> I seem to understand that the variables only would be passed from parent to child

Yes, props are always passed from parent to child. If you need other components to be able to access the state, you lift it up to a parent component.

> I made the Homescreen with a functional component which I understand is stateless

Function components are not stateless. They can hold state using the `useState` hook. Though your data needs to be in the root component and not home screen since you also need this data to be accessed by other screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. I've followed your advice and added a token which i store in the AsyncStorage. I've also added a new context, to pass the token to the child components, but i'm still having some difficulties with this. I will post my code in a new answer. Many thanks for the great help!

Comment: This answer deserves more visibility. Clear and well organised explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a utility class like DataHandler.js and save the user after login success

./DataHandler.js

```
let user = {};

export default {

  setUser(user) {
    user = user;
  },
  getUser() {
    return user;
  }
};
```

Usage like

```
import DataHandler from "./DataHandler";

saveUserName  = async (username) => {

    try {
        ......
        DataHandler.setUser(username); // Save User
        ......
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank for the reply! I'm already saving the username in the AsyncStorage. Doesn't saving it again make the AsyncStorage unnecessary? If i fill the DataHandler just once with the variable from the AsyncStorage, will i be able to access the variable on every screen? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes exactly that's the main reason saving in utility class. You just have to save once and can use it everywhere in app while using it.